# jQuery Version conversion issue for Lavalamp plugin

Tags: jquery, version, lavalamp

Here's the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xuforia/zZGsT/1/

I am trying to use a little plugin for menu animation.

However, I want to use it with the latest version of jQuery. It does everything I want it to do right now with jQuery version 1.5. However, I want to use it with latest version of jQuery i.e. 1.7.

Now if I change the jQuery version to 1.7, it wouldn't immediately. But if I change the mouseover event on the code *(marked by       ////////////////////////// Change hover to mouseover here ////////////////////////////// line)* to hover then it works.

Great, but one thing goes wrong. When you over over "what we do" a drop down menu appears. When you hover over any of the submenus, the red border on top of the menu goes wild. 
The problem didn't exist with mouseover instead of hover in jQuery 1.5.

Any suggestions on what the problem might be or if this can be fixed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your problem, but it might be an idea to create your own Lava Lamp style menu from scratch. Link to tutorial: [How to Build a Lava-Lamp Style Navigation Menu](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-lava-lamp-style-navigation-menu/)